# SQL query to UPDATE a column with a bit of a complicated IF condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update my `wp_posts` table. It has a field `post_content` that contains HTML for the post (including multiple a href links). My goal is to alter the HTML so that all hyperlinks (`<a>` tags) pointing at www.domain.com no longer have a `rel="nofollow"` attribute set if present, while not touching the other ones that point to other domains.

How can I write that statement in SQL?

> UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,'rel="nofollow"','') WHERE ... ?

So the condition is pretty much replace the nofollow tag in the  tag where href contains www.domain.com

Suggestions?

Comment: maybe if you gave us something to work with we could help... what is rel='nofollow' ? a string in the database? is the column name rel? where do the links in that table point to www.domain.com? whats different from that to another link? please when you write a question try to make it more informative and constructive :)

Comment: WHERE href LIKE 'www.domain.com%'?

Comment: Sounds like he has HTML stored in the post_content field. He's looking to parse the content and update only `<a>` tags that point to www.domain.com. For reference `rel='nofollow'` indicates a hyperlink that shouldn't be follows during search engine crawling. I'll (try) edit the question.

Comment: @AndySavage You're probably right.  Some example data would help immensely though.

Comment: If you mean that a comment might contain multiple hrefs and you only want to amend the hrefs for www.domain.com then you need an HTML parser. I'm not aware of any for MySQL. OTOH if it only can contain one href, then `WHERE post_content LIKE '%href=_http://www.domain.com%'` should suffice.

Comment: @symcbean, yes, that's exactly the issue. There are multiple hrefs and I only wanted to edit the ones with domain.com in them, leaving the others untouched.